Keyboard shortcut to open top-panel menu of the logout screen in Ubuntu?
After I'm done using my laptop, I always first log out and then shutdown my laptop. Now, I want to able to do that using keyboard shortcuts, and arrow keys to access the menu options from the menu.
I can use Ctrl + Alt + delete to bring up the Logout dialogue.

Is there a shortcut now-a-days to access the top panel menu using keyboard keys?


Just press Ctrl+Alt+T then type shutdown and hit Enter.  It will do both at once.

Since Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome Shell implemented the shortcut Ctrl+S to open the Status menu when you are logged in. Such shortcut key, however, is not available on the login screen.
In Ubuntu, the easiest keyboard-driven way to shut down a laptop is to hit Super, type "shu" (until the "Shut Down"  icon is highlighted) and hit Enter. Then, in the "Power Off" dialog, hit Tab then Enter.
You could set up your own custom shortcut key to quickly display the "Power Off"  dialog using "Settings" - "Keyboard" - "Custom shortcuts". Specify the following command: gnome-session-quit --power-off.
